# How to convert the argument of wp_list_pages to an array

Tags: menus, walker

I am working on a theme that calls

```
wp_list_pages('title_li=&sort_column=menu_order')
```

I need to put a walker class in that but the conditions has to be same.
I don't understand what 'title_li=&sort_column=menu_order' means and how to convert it to an array with the option to add a walker class ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are arguments in string form, which is just `key=value`, with an ampersand `&` separating each argument.

In the form of an array, they would be:

```
array(
    'title_li' => '',
    'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
);
```